# Calculating the error

Tags: visual-studio

I am doing corrections to controls for a UI application. Here is the requirement:

- The expected width and height as per specification is 490 x 340
- The visual studios(where i develop User Interface) it shows 339 x 161
- When I execute the application what i am getting is 506 x 260...

What is the correction I have to make in the Visual Studio if I have to get the expected 409 x 340 after execution.

I tried taking the ratios of expected as per spec and the application to get the correction. And later multiplying the correction to 339. Is that okay?

Comment: As VS is not a math object, and we don't really care about it here, we don't know what transformation it applies, so the answer may as well be **[42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29)**.

Comment: this MAY solve your problem, $\frac{339}{506}\approx 0.6699, \frac{161}{260}\approx 0.619$, $\therefore(490*0.6) \times (340*0.6)$

Comment: if you want to know whether you are doing it correctly, please show exact math, not a description.

Comment: BTW, why was this migrated to here? there's no programming involved.

Comment: The second bullet is wrong of course, you made it too small.  Solving the automatic 150% dpi scaling is easy, I'll swap your nice retina display for my crappy Dell monitor.